# Undefined error in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm building a file uploader that gets IPTC data from the image and inserts it into a db but I keep getting this error:

```
> A PHP Error was encountered
> 
> Severity: Notice
> 
> Message: Undefined index: 2#120
> 
> Filename: controllers/upload.php
> 
> Line Number: 63
```

Here's the line from the controller:

```
$iptc_description = $iptc["2#120"];
```

The script works perfectly as it's supposed to, but it keeps throwing up this error and I can't figure out why.

Comment: have you checked the `$iptc` if that index actually exists? try doing a `var_dump($iptc)` to check if it does.

Comment: Because `2#12` isn't set in `$iptc`, try using `print_r( $iptc)` and `= isset($iptc["2#120"]) ? $iptc["2#120"] : ''` instead of `= $iptc["2#120"]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace that line with (your using the variable before its set):

```
$iptc_description = (isset($iptc["2#120"]))?$iptc["2#120"]:null;
```

Or if you don't like one-liners:

```
$iptc_description = null;
if (isset($iptc["2#120"])) {
    $iptc_description = $iptc["2#120"];
}
```